# iterate through table to check which checkboxes have been clicked

Tags: php, javascript

I have a table that is populated from a mysql database (only 8 entries for testing at this stage).
With each record I include a checkbox called Visit.
When the user clicks the Print button I want to iterate through the table contents and check each checkbox to see which ones have been checked and then create an array from the checked boxes with values being $row[0] which is the id of each database record.

```
<table width="auto" border="1px" bordercolor="#999999" id="tbl">
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM Sales "; //WHERE startdate >= CurDate() ORDER BY startdate ";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
```

some more stuff here...

```
echo "<h2><font color=#000000>Visit&nbsp;<input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"fred[]\"
class=\"chcktbl\" value=\"$row[0]\" onclick=\"myfunct()\" /></font>$row[0]&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
$row[6]</h2><em><strong><font color = #FF0000>Sale is on $slongdate until $elongdate.
~ Times are $mystime to $myetime</strong></em></td>...
```

Here's the javascripts i have been trying...

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var visitcount =0;
var mylink =0;

/*    $('.chcktbl').click(function () { 
    visitcount = $('.chcktbl:checked').length;  
    mylink = $('.chcktbl').val();
    alert(mylink+' '+visitcount);
});
*/
function myfunct() {
mylink = document.getElementById('fred[]').value; 
alert('Hi There'+mylink);
}
```

Apologies if I have not shown the code correctly.
Hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient `mysql_*` functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Thanks for the tip about PDO and MYSQLi. I will take a look later and change my code when I have solved so more pressing issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function checkall_members() {
    var checkbox = document.getElementById("check_all");
    if (checkbox.checked) {
        ///your code
    }
    else {
       ///your code
    }
}
</script>
```